# How to apply sub function to a corpus or to a folder?

Tags: r

```
myDocument <- file.path(".", "politics")
myDocument;
text.corp <- Corpus(DirSource(myDocument))
text.corp;
```

I want to remove some pattern using sub function from politics directory which contains 1000 files. The sub function is applicable only text file so I am not getting how to do on directory. Please help me.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to subset the 1,000 files or so in your politics directory so that you can read in to R only files with a certain name structure?  Can you add to your question a sample of the file names and which kinds of file names you want (or don't want)?  You can run head(dir(politics) to create the sample

Comment: Newsgroups: talk.politics.guns
Path: cantaloupe.srv.cs.cmu.edu!crabapple.srv.cs.cmu.edu!bb3.an

Comment: These type of headers are there in every file in politics directory. That I want to remove

Answer (score 2):

You should use function `tm_map` like this:

```
text.corp.subed <- tm_map(text.corp, function(x) sub("Pattern", "Replacement", x))
```

You can learn more about `tm` package usage from it's documentation: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf

Comment: text.corp1<-tm_map(text.corp1, content_transformer(tolower))
Error in UseMethod("content", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'content' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: I am getting above error because of the tm_map function which I used for sub function. What may be the solution for this??

Comment: @KavitaShinde `tm_map(text.corp, content_transformer(function(x) sub("Pattern", "Replacement", x)))`